# How come that compiz knows/cares about searches in firefox?

Tags: firefox, compiz, search

While looking at the output of `journalctl -f` I noticed that apparently *compiz* is notified about (and logs) every search I make in the entry bar (or the search bar) in Firefox (but not in *Chromium*).

Typing into the entry bar something like

[image]

results in the following lines in my log

```
Okt 30 18:24:59 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:24:59 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats t"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+t"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats th"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+th"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:06 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the"
Okt 30 18:25:07 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:07 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the"
Okt 30 18:25:08 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the m"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:08 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+m"
Okt 30 18:25:08 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the ma"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:08 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+ma"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the mat"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+mat"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matt"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matt"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matte"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matte"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matter"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:09 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matter"
Okt 30 18:25:10 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matter?"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:10 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matter%3F"
Okt 30 18:25:21 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matter?"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:21 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matter%3F"
Okt 30 18:25:23 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: In data: "whats the matter?"; Purpose: "keyword"
Okt 30 18:25:23 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getSubmission: Out data: "whats+the+matter%3F"
```

It does not matter which search provider I have selected.
I would like to know what settings cause this behavior of compiz and how to prevent this.

<sub>In my opinion it is none of compiz's business what I type into a search bar in my webbrowser.</sub>

I do know that it is possible to circumvent this by entering search expressions directly into the search field of any search provider but that's not what I am after.

Upon further research I found the following additional lines in my log (after login):

```
Okt 30 17:37:30 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SearchService.init
Okt 30 17:37:30 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncInit start
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncLoadEngines: start
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncFindJAREngines: looking for engines in JARs
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncLoadEngines: loading from cache directories
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _loadEnginesFromCache: Loading 7 engines from cache
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Google"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "DuckDuckGo"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Amazon.com"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Bing"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Twitter"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Wikipedia (en)"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _addEngineToStore: Adding engine: "Yahoo"
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncLoadEngines: done
Okt 30 17:37:31 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _asyncInit: Completed _asyncInit
Okt 30 17:37:33 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SearchService.init
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SearchService.init
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getVisibleEngines: getting all visible engines
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _buildSortedEngineList: building list
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: _buildSortedEngineList: using db for order
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SRCH_SVC_saveSortedEngineList: starting
Okt 30 17:37:49 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SRCH_SVC_saveSortedEngineList: done
Okt 30 17:37:53 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: SearchService.init
Okt 30 17:37:53 big compiz[9072]: *** Search: getVisibleEngines: 
getting all visible engines
```

*Settings/Security and Privacy/Search* ("when searching in the dash...") is **off**.

Comment: @Rinzwind they are disabled (if you are talking about "When searching in dash").

Comment: weird.the things shown in your logs I only see in relation to a browser (firefox)

Comment: ALSO WEIRD: I do NOT see this happening on my system.

Comment: another stupid question: does it happen in chromium? :D any plugins in FF you installed?

Comment: Plugins: a "few", but I'd be *very surprised*™ if that would cause the system to register search providers on **login** already.